# How to setup hostapd as service if "hostapd: unrecognized service"?

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I've make and install hostapd from sources on my raspi 2 Raspbian. But how to run it as a service?

```
sudo service hostapd start
```

returns
    hostapd: unrecognized service

In case of update-rc.d:

```
update-rc.d hostapd enable
```

returns

```
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
update-rc.d: error: cannot find a LSB script for hostapd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`service` is kind of a shortcut to saying `/etc/init.d`. So I guess you don't have a `hostapd` file with permissions 755 (by `chmod 755`, which means read write execute for owner, read execute for group and read execute for others) in `/etc/init.d`.

What I suggest is you should make a clean reinstall, if your WiFi dongle is compatible I can suggest this tutorial : http://elinux.org/RPI-Wireless-Hotspot

You can check compatibility by `iw list | grep AP`.

Hope this helps.